# Multiple files on FormData() append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add an array of images in FormData, but only the first image is passing.

I know the problem is in the JS code because when I send the form direct to the php page, it works fine.

JavaScript

```
var url = $(this).attr('action');
var data = new FormData();

$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('image[]', file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<label for="1">Image 1</label>
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="1"/>

<label for="1">Image 2</label>
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="2" />

<label for="1">Image 3</label>
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="3" />
```

Comment: **Typo:** by doing `$("input[type='file']")[0].files` you are iterating over all the files of the first input only (`[0]`). What you want is `$("input[type='file']").each(function(i, input) { $.each(input.files, function(j, file) {data.append...` Or, since none of your inputs has the `multiple` attribute, `$("input[type='file']").each(function(i, input) {data.append('image[]', input.files[0])})`

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('input[type=file]'), function(i, value) 
{
    data.append('image['+i+']', value.files[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For Vanilla JS, I like to use Array.from and loop through each element like this

```
let data = new FormData();
let input_file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

Array.from(input_file.files).forEach((f) => {
    data.append('image[]', f)
})
```